# Mysterious Italic Text on Blog Post

Tags: wordpress, blogs, italics

I have a paragraph of text on a Wordpress blog post that is completely set in italics. The document and HTML has no "em" contained inside. I'm totally stumped. Anyone know what can be causing this.

Answer (score 0):

There is likely some CSS on the page that is acting on that blog post.

You can try searching the CSS file or files loaded on the page for `font-style: italic;` or search for the classes that are assigned to that blog post's elements to see how they are being styled.